# How do I know if it is Partial View?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

How can I find out whether the file with .cshtml extension is View or Partial View? Is this situation stated somewhere?

[image]

thanks.

Comment: I don’t think you can completely guess this from the file since it depends on how the file is being used. E.g. you can call the same cshtml using `View` from a controller, or include it from another view making it a partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0#declare-partial-views) related:

> Partial view file names often begin with an underscore (_). This
> naming convention isn't required, but it helps to visually
> differentiate partial views from views and pages.

A view could be used as partial view as well,the most difference is partial view doesn't run _ViewStart.cshtml,and partial view file usually begin with `_`